# I updated my iPad Air to iOS 8 and keychain not working correctly

Tags: keychain, ios, ipad

After updating my iPad Air to iOS 8, keychain is not working correctly.  It will occasionally ask to save new login data but never offers to fill in that info when I go to that website.  All the logins from iOS 7 are in the password file but it never uses any of the old data nor ask to save those websites again.  The password file has the four digit password which I did not have on iOS 7.  I have checked the settings several times and tried different settings and nothing works.  The settings appear to be correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS is a sandbox I do not know of any tools to help reset the keychain and download it again with out resetting all settings. Do you have the iCloud Keychain running, is it backed up via iCloud? If so then trying to reinstall your iCloud data back may fix the issue. Start by going to Setting> General>Reset reset all settings. If this does not work try  erase all content and settings and restore from and iCloud backup. If you are still acing issues the try a  full erase of the iOS and your data. Then restore from an iCloud backup.

Answer (score 0):

If your keyboard is in “split” mode, then the keychain/password option does not show up in the middle of the bottom of the screen. Un-split your onscreen keyboard (tap both sides of the keyboard at the same time and slide your fingers inward) and keychain should show up again when you click into the user or password boxes.